# Automatically switch default Sound Input Device

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

I bought a new microphone that's attached to my desk, in addition to my Logitech G930 Wireless Headset with a hinge up mic.

When I sit at my desk, I'd like my Microphone there to be the default device. Once I leave my desk and hinge down the headset microphone, I'd like my default input device to switch to that one.

When I physically mute/hinge up my headphones, apparently it sends some kind of event to my OS, since it knows that it's muted and displays it e.G. here:

[[image]]

I've done some research and found Software like [nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#using), but how I see it, there's no way to get the mute state. Apparently it can be done with C++ CoreAudio I'd rather not Download a 3GB Compiler and Visual Studio just for a ten-liner.

Are there any CoreAudio Bindings for other languages like Python or Node.js/Alternative Tools to achieve what I need?

Comment: c# can do it [no probs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663135/windows-10-get-system-audio-mute-status-in-c-sharp).  Since c# can do it.. chances are you can access the same classes from powershell.  Python nor NodeJS are native to windows and don't have deep roots into the windows API (unlike .net).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks for your response but I'd rather not Download a 3GB Compiler and Visual Studio just for a ten-liner.

Comment: The "compiler" is already on your system (like it or not) for c# .. powershell doesn't even use one.  Technically, all you need is a text editor.  What is this about 3gb?  If you are comfortable with these other languages and would like to do it from there.. just say so.  This has nothing to do with the size of a compiler download (for a ten liner).  Do you want to fix this or not?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas really? I've been under the impression that i need the visual studio installer + the build tools to compile c# and c++. Since my connection is really poor, this will take several hours to download

Comment: You already have the c# compiler on your system (we all do).  All you need is a decent editor.  Powershell (which can also do this) is also already on your system and isn't compiled at all.  I am not being of much use here because these things are not what you asked for and how I feel about it isn't how SU works :)  good luck!

Comment: it's fine, thanks for taking the time. Could you link me to a resource on how to do this with C++ or C#? Everything I find tells me to download visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around to solving this using https://github.com/frgnca/AudioDeviceCmdlets/ within a PowerShell-Script.

```
$Microphone = "{0.0.1.00000000}.{50486949-aae2-4574-97fb-4660fd26b6f7}"
$Headset = "{0.0.1.00000000}.{4bf15a7e-d091-4bcb-ae8f-5cadfdcffca7}"

while (1) {
    $ActiveDevice = Get-AudioDevice -Recording
    $HeadSetObject = Get-AudioDevice -ID $Headset
    $HeadSetIsMuted = $HeadSetObject."Device"."AudioEndpointVolume"."Mute"
    if ($HeadSetIsMuted) {
        if ($ActiveDevice."ID" -eq $HeadSet) {
            Set-AudioDevice -ID $Microphone
        }
    } else {
        if ($ActiveDevice."ID" -eq $Microphone) {
            Set-AudioDevice -ID $Headset
        }
    }
    
    sleep 3;
}
```